# Choose which plants to build to maximise profit

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, summation, mathematical-modeling, constraints

[image]

---

[image]

---

What I tried:

Let $y_i = 1$

if plant $i$ is to be constructed and $0$ otherwise

Let $c_{ij}$ be transportation cost per-unit for whatever the plants produce delivered from plant $i$ to customer $j$.

Let $x_{ij}$ be units of whatever delivered from plant $i$ to customer $j$.

Min

$$z = [12000, 11000, 12000] \cdot [y_1, y_2, y_3] + \sum_i \sum_j c_{ij} x_{ij}$$

s.t.

1. supply

$$\sum_j x_{1j} y_1 \le 1800 \color{red}{+ M(1-y_i)}$$

$$\sum_j x_{2j} y_2 \le 1400 \color{red}{+ M(1-y_i)}$$

$$\sum_j x_{3j} y_3 \le 1300 \color{red}{+ M(1-y_i)}$$

$\color{red}{\text{I have a feeling that this is redundant by constraint 3.}}$

2. demand

$$\sum_i x_{i1} \ge 1200$$

$$\sum_i x_{i2} \ge 1700$$

$$\sum_i x_{i3} \ge 1600$$

3. $x_{ij} \le My_i$

---

From Chapter 3 [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABIU1apSS8r3CbA&id=5EA51B764D593198%212679&cid=5EA51B764D593198).

Comment: You need to link the $x$ and $y$ variables with $x_{ij}\le My_i$, where $M$ is a large constant.

Comment: @Kuifje I need to keep $x_{ij}$ as is?

Comment: $x_{ij}$ should be a binary that equals 1 if plant $i$ produces for client $j$.

Comment: @Kuifje Ah thanks ^-^ Okay now?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @Kuifje Thanks ^-^ Post as answer? Might you please check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698179/maximise-population-coverage-subject-to-budget-constraint) out as well?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_{ij}$ be a binary that equals $1$ if and only plan $i$ produces for customer $j$, and $y_i$ another binary that equals $1$ if and only if plant $i$ is built. Let $c_{ij}$ be the transportation cost from plant $i$ to customer $j$ and $f_i$ the fixed of building plant $i$.
$$
\mbox{Minimize } Z=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3c_{ij}x_{ij}+\sum_{i=1}^3f_{i}y_i
$$
subject to

- Limited supplies :$\sum_{j=1}^3 p_{ij}x_{ij}\le s_i\quad \forall i=1,2,3$
- Meet demands: $\sum_{i=1}^3 p_{ij}x_{ij}\ge d_j\quad \forall j=1,2,3$
- Link variables: $x_{ij}\le My_i\quad \forall i,j=1,2,3$
- Variables are binary: $x_{ij},y_i\in \{0,1\} \quad \forall i,j=1,2,3$

Comment: Hey Kuifje, I edited my post. How is it? On your answer: 1 I think $p_{ij}$ is not needed in constraints. 2 Is your $p_{ij}$ equal to your $c_{ij}$ ? 3 is your $p_{ij}$ equal to my $x_{ij}$?